# pymodbus: get data from input registers paralleling using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pymodbus

I am using **pymodbus** library to get data from sensors using the below multiprocessing code

```
def Get_Latest_Sensor_Data(tInput_Device_ID_List):
      
    sub_df = tInput_df[tInput_df["device_id"] == tInput_Device_ID_List]
    sub_df = sub_df.reset_index()

    tIP_Addr = sub_df.iloc[0]['ip_addr']
    tIP_Port = sub_df.iloc[0]['ip_port']
    tDevice_ID = sub_df.iloc[0]['device_id']
    tActive_Energy_Addr = sub_df.iloc[0]['active_energy_addr']
    
    client = ModbusTcpClient(tIP_Addr, port=int(tIP_Port), timeout=10)
    connection = client.connect()
    
    tData_Len = 2
    request = client.read_input_registers(int(tActive_Energy_Addr), tData_Len, unit=int(tDevice_ID))
    result = request.registers

    decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(request.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)
    active_power_w = decoder.decode_32bit_int()
               
        
    return tFinal_df


tInput_List = {
    "ip_addr": ["<IP_ADDR>", "<IP_ADDR>"],
    "ip_port": [502, 502],
    "device_id":[51, 52],
    "active_energy_addr": [220, 220]
}

tInput_df = pd.DataFrame(tInput_List)

tInput_IP_List = tInput_df['ip_addr'].tolist()
tInput_Device_ID_List = tInput_df['device_id'].tolist()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    tResult = pool.map(Get_Latest_Sensor_Data, tInput_Device_ID_List)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(tResult)
```

I can see that this code is working and i could able to get the energy meter reading as well.

But since the **Get_Latest_Sensor_Data()** runs twice, i can see that the **client connection is getting established twice** and increases as I increase my processes value.
I tried creating the connection before calling the Pool.map() function and it throws error if mre than one device id is being used.

Is there a way to establish the connection to the IP_ADDR only once and get energy  meter reading for n number of device id that will be passed.

Is this possible in Pool.map() or do i need to use something else ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Before calling the Pool.map() function, create a connection and pass it as an argument to Get_Latest_Sensor_Data, or you can use the asyncio library.

Comment: @cardosource, thanks for replying. I tried creating the connection before but cant able to pass the connection obj as it says obj is not iteratable. i will look into the asyncio library.

Comment: In order for Pool.map() to work correctly, you need to pass a list of arguments that can be iterated.

Comment: @cardosource, i understood that part, i am asking is there a way to create a connection just once and do the read_input_registers() for multiple device id's of same register address parallelly

Comment: @SM079 depends, are all of the devices on the same physical connection? If yes (say, you have a USB-RS485 with multiple servers daisy-chained), then all you do is iterate reading the registers you want over the multiple server/slave addresses. If your devices do not share the same physical connection, then you'd have to re-initialize the client with the proper arguments each time you want to speak to a new device. There are ways to have that be automated, as discussed above.